# Excel - Placing values that fall within a certain time range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following data on duration of particular services.

```
     A                          B                C                      D
Usage Start (Local time)    Start Time  Usage Until (Local time)    End Time
03.03.2018 10:00           12:00:00 AM     03.03.2018 00:00      1:00:00 AM
03.03.2018 00:00            1:00:00 AM     03.03.2018 00:00      2:00:00 AM
03.03.2018 16:30            1:00:00 AM     03.03.2018 00:00      3:00:00 AM
```

And I want to count the number of times a timing falls within a certain range(eg. 00:00 - 01:00)

```
     Start  End  Counts
     00:00  01:00   1
     01:00  02:00   2
     02:00  03:00   1
     03:00  04:00   
     04:00  05:00   
     05:00  06:00
```

What formula should I use and how do I apply it?

I have tried this

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$566,">="&A2,$D$2:$D$566,"<"&B2)
```

And this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$566>= A2)*($D$2:$D$566< B2))
```

But it doesn't account for more than 24 hour duration (Eg.3/3/2018 1:00 PM - 4/3/2018 2:00 PM, 25 hours)

Comment: It seems you want to **COUNT IF** two scenarios match. Research COUNTIFS.

Comment: Hi, sorry if it is misleading. The 3rd entry, has a timing of 1-3 AM breaking it down into (1-2 AM, 2-3 AM) hence there are 4 entries/counts.

Comment: @bobby Do the "tasks" always start and end on the same day? Or is that just a coincidence in the data you provided?

Comment: @Rawrplus No the "tasks" could end on a different day eg 3/3/2018 - 4/3/2018.

Comment: @Jeeped Yeah i have been trying to look at many articles on this.

Comment: @bobby so eg. if the task started 7:00 AM 1/1/18 and ended on 8:00 AM 2/1/18 the count would be 25, right?

Comment: @Rawrplus Yes that is correct.

Comment: I'm not getting where your counts are coming from.  I take it the 25 that @Rawrplus said is because it's 25 hours, but how do the counts in the second table relate to the figures in the first table? What have you counted to get 1, 2 & 1?  I _think_ `Frequency` might help from where you said _i want to count the number of times a timing falls on a certain range_ but don't know how your data is working.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes, Frequency is what i am trying to get.

Comment: Good, but I just don't get how your data works. Your comment to @Rawrplus says _Trying to achieve a table where if i have a 25 hours usage, 00:00-01:00 will have a count of "2" and the rest til 23:00-00:00 a count of "1"_  but I don't see why 00:00-1:00 will have a count of "2" and the rest a count of "1". Why is that?  Although that might be because I can't see the images in the post.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Lets say it is from 3/3/2018 12:00:00 AM - 4/3/2018 1:00:00 AM A total of 25 hours.  And i have a table of 00:00-01:00, 01:00-02:00, 02:00-03:00.... 23:00-24:00.  The times that 00:00-01:00 have occurred in this instance is "2" and the rest of the time slots "1". My goal is to find the frequency for a 24 hour time frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're ignoring the time portion in Columns `A` and `C`. Assuming your start/end hour bins are in columns `F` and `G`, the formula below will give you the number of times that an event passed through your first hour bin (you have to enter it as an array formula--<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>). Fill down for subsequent hour bins.

```
=SUM(($B$2:$B$4<F2+TIME(0,30,0))+($D$2:$D$4>F2+TIME(0,30,0))+INT($C$2:$C$4)-INT($A$2:$A$4)-1)
```

This will count an event in an hour bin if the event is active at the half-hour mark.

If the event needs to cover the entire time bin, use this formula (again with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=SUM(($B$2:$B$4<=F2)+IF(G2>F2,($D$2:$D$4>=G2))+INT($C$2:$C$4)-INT($A$2:$A$4)-1)
```

Comment: Hi could you explain to me how this works? Thank you

Comment: Start times such as 7:45 AM, 10:45 AM does not go into 07:00, and 10:00 bins. Also, End times such as 00:15,00:30 does not get recorded in 00:00.

Comment: @bobby I've updated with a simplified formula. It should be easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Was a bit more complicated than I expected, but I got it to work.

> Though before we start, you need to format your table a little. **You
>   can't have date and time in the same cell** (as excel has trouble
>   recognizing storing two formats in 1 cell).
>   Instead format your table
>   like so:

[image]

Next we should create some hidden rows *(technically you can stick what I'm about to do in 1 giant formula, but for sake of clarity I prefer hidden rows)*

First we focus on the time difference in hours. Creating the two following columns

> Also, make sure, you set the format in these newly added rows to
>   number. Technically it will work without it, but it will look
>   confusing to human eye

[image]

In the **Time defference** we use the following formula
`=ABS(F2-C2) * 24`

In the **overnight h** column:
`=IF(C2>F2, 24-G2, G2)` This is utilized that we properly count with transition dates (eg. 23:00 1/1/18 -> 01:00 2/1/18) we don't want to add the extra 24 hours in this case.

> That would be the hours fully working, but we also need to ensure the
>   formula works, when there's more than one night of difference (eg.
>   1/1/18 -> 3/1/18)

Next, we add these these two rows

[image]

In the **date difference column**, as the column name suggests
`=DATEDIF(A2, D2, "d") * 24`

Last but not least, the **overnight delta** is basically the same principle as overnight h, but with dates instead of hours

So now, if we have hidden the rows, added the following formula to result `=H2+I2-J2` we get our  sought after table:

[image]

*Which corresponds with the expected result! :)*

---

**EDIT**: If you don't want to take hours into cosnideration and only count how many times an interval of 24 hours has expired use the following formula

`=IF(C2>F2, DATEDIF(A2, D2, "d")-1, DATEDIF(A2, D2, "d"))`

*(under presumption c2,f2,a2,d2 are in the columns as in my original table i provided)*

[image]

Comment: Thank You for this, but how do i place these so called "Result" in the fields that i mentioned above? The 24 hour time stamp (00:00-01:00, 02:00-03:00)

Comment: @bobby, the issue is, you can't have the time format exceeding 24hours, which is possible (eg. 25 or 50 hours as in my result). What exactly is the format you want to achieve? (because `Start: 01:00 | End: 51:00` doesn't make much sense to me)

Comment: Trying to achieve a table where if i have a 25 hours usage, 00:00-01:00 will have a count of "2" and the rest til 23:00-00:00 a count of "1". I want to use this table to create a chart to display the highest usage during the day.

Comment: You could have cleared that sooner *(in your original question)*... I wouldn't have bothered with how to calculate hours properly for 20 minutes then.

Comment: Sorry about that, I appreciate your help in this. The answer you gave me was insightful.

Comment: @bobby check my answer, edited it. Hopefully it is as expected now.

Comment: Thank you, this will be useful to me too.

Comment: I mean, probably best thing would be if you gave me the proper format you're seeking (pictures!) and I can create a formula for that so we don't go back and forth here. So we can finally consider this question/answer as solved